# Nice way to increment unset variable / new key in array

Tags: php, lazy-initialization

For some reason i often found my self to do something like that:

```
foreach($source as $key => $value) {
    if (!isset($arr[$key])) {
        $arr[$key] = 0; // or any other value
    }
    $arr[$key] += something($value);
}
```

When i have a well known source of data sometimes i do just:

```
foreach($source as $key => $value) {
    @$arr[$key] += something($value);
}
```

to avoid log spamming ( i do not want to remove warning or notices from logs)

Is there any other more compact or smarter or just prettier way to do this?

Comment: If you want something smart and compact just compose a huge ternary operator in a single line. If you prefer legibility just stick to your original code.

Comment: isn't array key is set on inside of if ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

PHP7 has the easiest option:

```
$arr[$key] = ($arr[$key] ?? 0) + something($value);
```

If you're not on the bleeding edge of updates, you're stuck with this more verbose, but equally correct version:

```
$arr[$key] = (isset($arr[$key]) ? $arr[$key] : 0) + something($value);
```

You shouldn't suppress errors for something as simple as this.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
$arr[$key] = (array_key_exists($key, $arr) ? $arr[$key] : 0) + 10;
```

But I don't think that the above code is more readable than

```
if (!array_key_exists($key, $arr)) {
    $arr[$key] = 0;
}
$arr[$key] += 10;
```

**Sidenote isset vs. array_key_exists**

array_key_exists() purely checks if the key exists, even if the value is NULL.

Whereas isset() will return false if the key exist and value is NULL.

For performance isset() is faster

Comment: Thanks, saw it and I personally prefer array_key_exists in this case cause the code is a lot more self explaining. But I don't know if its better than just with if. The Code with if is a lot more readable.